# What's the difference between a family close under countable disjoint unions and a family close under countable unions?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Could you give examples of families close under countable disjoint unions and close under countable unions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any family closed under countable unions is clearly closed under countable *disjoint* unions. However, the converse is not true. For example, consider the set $$\mathcal{U}=\{\{1, 2\},\{1, 3\}\}.$$ This set is definitely *not* closed under countable, or even finite!, unions, but it is *trivially* closed under arbitrary disjoint unions since its two elements are *not disjoint*.

Comment: My keyboard has been a bit wonky since some gin and tonic got spilled over it. I blame that. ;-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Muahahaha!

Answer (score 4):

Look at the family $\{\mathbb N\setminus\{n\}\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$. This family is certainly not closed under finite unions, let alone countable unions. Because taking any two different sets, their union is $\Bbb N$ itself which is not in the collection. But the family *is* closed under disjoint union, simply because no two sets are disjoint!

In the context of measure theory, we often think about $\sigma$-algebras, which are closed also under complements and intersection. There if we have any countable union $\bigcup A_n$, we can write it as a disjoint union $\bigcup B_n$, where $B_n=A_n\setminus\bigcup_{k<n}A_k$. And therefore the two things are equivalent for an algebra of sets: being closed under countable unions and under countable disjoint unions.